# Tool for Reverse Engineering of PostgreSQL Database on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: database-design, postgresql, linux, ubuntu, erd

Please suggest a tool to reverse engineer a PostgreSQL DB into an entity-relationship-diagram (ERD) or equivalent ??

Ideally, I'm looking for a simple ERD or UML class diagram in a format that is easy to work with (SVG, PDF or any common UML file format).

So far, I founded only software for MySQL and it's for Windows, 
but that's not solution.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937723/high-quality-erd-generator-for-postgresql-under-linux The accepted answer runs on Linux: http://www.dbschema.com/download.html

Comment: Quite often people have Visio pro just lying around, and it's got a passably good DB reverse engineering function.  May or may not be relevant to the OP but it's a good standby in many cases.

Comment: visual-paradigm has postgresql port too. www.visual-paradigm.com free version also does.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at at (the order of the items implies my personal choices)

- DbSchema (not free, but not expensive: http://dbschema.com/)
- SchemaSpy (http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/)
- Power*Architect (http://code.google.com/p/power-architect/) although development seems to have stopped)

All of them work with PostgreSQL (and other DBMS)

(Note: I have nothing to do with DbSchema. I just think it's a pretty good tool)

Answer (score 0):

pg_autodoc is what I have used.  It converts to dia UML diagrams.  Seems to work ok.  http://www.rbt.ca/autodoc/

Comment: does this work on newer version of PostgreSQL? 8.x and above?

Comment: I have used it on 7.x through 9.x.

Comment: That creates a table diagram. Getting from there to an entity-relationship diagram is another step.